# Android Emulator sometimes starts with No Service

Tags: android, emulation, internet-connection

Sometimes the emulator will start and it will say No Service and the internet connections will stop working. Then I restart the emulator once (or twice sometimes) and the next time it works.

How can I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a sollution, I certainly don't see how the answr @selladurai links to will help here.

This does happen to me once in a while too, on various systems (It has happened on Windows and Ubuntu, I *think* also on Mac, but I'm not sure). The only "sollution" seems to be what you are suggesting yourself: restart the emulator. This just seems to be one of the instabilities of the emulator.